# TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url' using ChromeDriver and Chrome through Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, positional-parameter

Following code is supposed to open Google chrome and Walmart page, but I came across the error below.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 

driver = webdriver.Chrome

driver.get('https://www.walmart.com/')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abdushukur/PycharmProjects/cloudacademy/automation.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver.get('https://www.walmart.com/')
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

Comment: I don't know Selenium, but by the look of it, I think you need to create an instance of a driver (with parentheses) `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

Answer (score 0):

The [Selenium docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) provides a small example on how to get started which shows that you need to create an instance of your driver (As FlorianGD mentioned in their comment) before you can get a URL from it. So your code would be -

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.walmart.com/")
```

*This does assume that the `chromedriver` is in the same directory as the executed script. If it is not you need to specify the path to the `chromedriver`

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate the location of your chromedriver in

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("your_chromedriver_path")
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is **`driver = webdriver.Chrome()`**. So in your code block you need to replace the line `driver = webdriver.Chrome` with:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Additionally, you may need to pass the *absolute path* of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) binary as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
```